# Sonata Admin-bundle : Submit values from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, sonata-admin

Exactly the same problem as this question :

[Dropdown Ajax onchange SonataAdminBundle Symfony2 Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798777/dropdown-ajax-onchange-sonataadminbundle-symfony2-issue)

when i select "value 1" dropdown, the form send an ajax request to my curstom CRUD controller which returns values which appends my second dropdown ( "id de l'element" ).

[image]

Everything works fine, in fact, but when i want to submit all the form to create my new object, sonata throws an error, and all my previous selected values are gone .

[image]

After digging in the generated html code, i confirm that my ajax request fills correctly the second select ( "id de l'element" ) which is used to display the dropdown.

but sonata doesn't seems to get the correct values .

any ideas ?

EDITED :

I made a small trick but it's really casual.

i filled the possible choices in my formMapper with an array of 2000 index (made with a simple loop )

since i'm only need integer key , it's work but it's not generic and it takes a lot of time for the dom to generate the 2000 options in my select.

i can't imagine that sonata developer didn't make their bundle usable with ajax request .....

My entity

```
  namespace myapp\AppBundle\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * statistics
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
  class Statistics
  {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstValue", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $firstValue;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="filter1", type="string")
 */
private $filter1;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="secondValue", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $secondValue;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="filter2", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $filter2;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="periodicity", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $periodicity;
```

here is my statistics admin class :

```
class statisticsAdmin extends Admin
 {
protected $baseRouteName                = 'stats';
protected $baseRoutePattern             = 'stats';

private $em;
private $bundles;
private $entities;
private $app;

public $filter1Values;
public $filter2Values;


public function getTemplate($name)
{
    if ( $name == "edit" )
        return 'bonkAppBundle:Admin:base_edit.html.twig' ;
    return parent::getTemplate($name);
}

/**
 * Récupères l'ensemble des entités disponible pour le projet
 * en cours.
 *
 * On fait établit un filtre pour éviter que le bundle FOSUser
 * soit pris en compte (il est inclus depuis l'entiti User
 *
 * les données collectés sont enregistrés dans une variable de class
 * $this->bundles
 * @return null
 */
public function getAllEntities()
{
    $this->em                       = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager('bonk\AppBundle\Entity\Statistics');
    $this->bundles                  = $this->em->getConfiguration()->getMetadataDriverImpl()->getAllClassNames();
    $this->app                      = 'bonk';

    foreach ( $this->bundles as $bundle )
    {
        $temp                       = explode ( '\\', $bundle );

        if ( $temp[0] == 'bonk' ){
            $class                  = $this->em->getClassMetadata( $temp[0].$temp[1].":".$temp[3] );
            $associations           = $class->getAssociationNames();

            //foreach ( $class->fieldMappings as $field )
            //    $this->entities[$temp[0].$temp[1].":".$temp[3]][$temp[0].$temp[1].":".$temp[3].":".$field['fieldName']] = $field['fieldName'] ;

            // on ajoute les relations de l'entite . We also add associations for the given entity class
            foreach ( $associations as $association ){
                $AssociatedEntity   = explode ( "\\", $class->getAssociationTargetClass( $association ) );
                $this->entities[$temp[0].$temp[1].":".$temp[3]][$AssociatedEntity[0].$AssociatedEntity[1].":".$AssociatedEntity[3]] = $association ;
            }
        }
    }
}


protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $this->getAllEntities();

    $temp = array();
    //for ( $a = 1; $a < 2000 ; $a++ )
    //    $temp[$a] = "a";

    $formMapper
        ->with('General')
            ->add('name', null, array ( 'label' => 'Titre') )
            ->add('firstValue', 'choice', array ( 'label' => 'Valeur 1', 'choices' => $this->entities ) )
            ->add('filter1' , 'choice' , array ( 'choices' => array('all' => 'Tout') ) )
            ->add('secondValue','choice', array ( 'label' => 'Valeur 2', 'choices' => $this->entities ) )
            ->add('filter2' , 'choice' , array ( 'choices' => array('all' => 'Tout') ) )
            ->add('periodicity','choice', array ( 'label' => 'Durée'   , 'choices' => array( 
                                                    '1 hour'    => '1 Heure',
                                                    '1 day'     => '1 Jour',
                                                    '1 week'    => '1 Semaine', 
                                                    '1 month'   => '1 Mois',
                                                    '3 months'  => '1 Trimestre',
                                                    '6 months'  => '1 Semestre',
                                                    '1 year'    => '1 Annee',
                                                    '2 year'    => '2 Annees' ) ) )
        ->end()
    ;
}

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('name', null, array ( 'label' => 'Titre') )
            ->add('firstValue', null, array ( 'label' => 'Valeur 1') )
            ->add('filter1', null, array ( 'label' => 'filtre 1') )
            ->add('secondValue', null, array ( 'label' => 'Valeur 2') )
            ->add('filter2', null, array ( 'label' => 'filtre 2') )
            ->add('periodicity', null, array ( 'label' => 'Durée') )
            ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'Clone' => array('template' => 'bonkAppBundle:CRUD:stat.html.twig'),
                'edit' => array(),
                'delete' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'error_mapping' => array(
            'test' => 'filter1Ajax',
        ),
    ));
}


/**
 * Ajoute une route pour l'admin
 *
 * La nouvelle vue sera disponible par la route spécifiée dans
 * $collection par la méthode "add"
 */
protected function configureRoutes( RouteCollection $collection )
{
    $collection->add('stat', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/stat');
}
```

then my javascript inside my custom overriding of base_edit.html.twig :

```
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset( 'public/js/chosen.jquery.min.js' ) }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var firstValue          = $("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_firstValue");
        firstValue.change(updateValues('firstValue'));

        var secondValue         = $("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_secondValue");
        secondValue.change(updateValues('secondValue', true ));

        function updateValues(value, secondValue = false){
            return function () {

                if ( secondValue == false ){
                    var tagId   = $("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_firstValue option:selected").val();
                    var filter1 = $("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_filter1");
                }else{
                    var tagId   = $("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_secondValue option:selected").val();
                    var filter1 = $("#{{ admin.uniqId }}_filter2");
                }

                filter1.empty();
                filter1.trigger("chosen:updated");

                var locale      = '{{ app.request.get('_locale') }}';
                var objectId    = '{{ admin.id(object) }}'

                $.ajax
                ({
                    type:   'POST',
                    url :   Routing.generate('myapp_admin_get_values_from_entities', { '_locale': locale, 'tagId': tagId, _sonata_admin: 'myapp.app.admin.stats', id: objectId }) ,
                    data:   tagId,
                    cache:  false,
                    error:function ( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ) 
                    {
                        alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
                    },
                    success:function( html )
                    {
                        filter1.empty();
                        filter1.append(html);
                        filter1.trigger("chosen:updated");
                        filter1.val('option:first').attr('selected', true );
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question by adding your entity definitions please? :)

Comment: udpated . i also added my js from my overrided base_edit.html.twig

Comment: Nothing in error.log ?

Comment: i haven't an error.log in my symfony log dir . how can i enable it ? i have only dev.log

Comment: there's no FormType (AbstractType) for the entity?
if yes, provide it

Comment: @ROLO This is sonata, so no formType inside , just an admin class, i update my question.

Comment: there is only one case that pops in my mind, your js populates the form fields with wrong names and the validation on the server side rejects the form (that's the usual behavior in symfony)

p.s. does sonata have a debug panel like in "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle()"?

Comment: yes, in the formfield my filter1 as , by default, only one values ('all') because i cant predict what will be feed by my ajax request, since it can be anything from different entities.